# Freemarker convert a string to a number without rounding and get the absolute value

Tags: java, json, freemarker

I'm new to Freemarker templates. I want to convert a string to a number without rounding any decimal values and then get the absolute value of that.

Example:

```
<#if a.value?is_string>
            <#if a.value?number &lt; 0>
                "aValue": "${a.value?number?abs}"
            <#else>
                "aValue": "${a.value}"
            </#if>
</#if>
```

When I do the above, when converting the string to the number, Freemarker rounds the value first and get the absolute value of that.

If I pass -1.234567 as a.value, then it gives 1.235. The expected result would be 1.234567 (This should be inside the first if block)

Please help if someone knows the answer. Thanks.

Comment: You could always use `a.value?number?abs` instead of that `#if`/`#else`. If you are afraid of losses when parsing+formatting, you can just use `${a.value?remove_beginning('-')}`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not because of `?number`. That doesn't do any rounding. The loss happens when convert the number back to string. That does localized formatting according the `number_format` setting, which must be something like `"0.###"` there.

If the number you output will be parsed again by a program, then always format with `?c`, like `${a.value?abs?c}`. `?c` always uses dot as decimal separator, and it never uses grouping separators (like 3,000,000), and shows up to 16 digits after the dot.